# C# interfaces share between different svn projects

Tags: c#, svn, interface

I’m a C++ guy which has to work with some C# projects hence I have question. Having two projects placed on different svn servers I need them to share interface classes. How it should be solved in C#.
For example I have cs file which have interface and class used to pass data to the interface i.e.

```
Public Class data
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
Public Interface Ifoo
{
    int foo(data);
}
```

This interface is implemented in ProjectA and used by ProjectB.
I want to be able to chose implementation of the interface so that in tests of ProjectB  I will use special implementation of Ifoo interface.Chosing different dll using :

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(asm_name);
 fooer = assembly.CreateInstance(class_name) as Ifoo;
```

Where I should place Ifoo interface?
I thought it should  be placed in ProjectA svn repo (as ProjectA is owner of the interface) and then checkout it as an external with checkout of ProjectB .

Can you tell me what is the rule of thumb in such case?

BR
Krzysztof

Comment: Why do you need to use another implementation of interface in tests? Are you making tests for interfaces? oO

Comment: I want only to Test ProjectB no ProjectB together with ProjectA so using simple dll I can manipulate results of the interface function calls and test its influence on projectB.

Comment: I would move all shareable interfaces into ProjectC and would reference ProjectC in both ProjectA and ProjectB as an external source.

Comment: Hello but then you lose track of who is the owner of this interface and for the example it is clearly ProjectA

Comment: Purpose of moving shared interfaces to the separate project (ProjectC) is quite obvious - to define some shared abstractions that you can reuse across different projects, but if you think that you can relate your interface to any single project that probably means that you don't need to share that interface.

Comment: Yes I do relate interface to single project. I want to introduce interface to decouple ProjectB from ProjectA so that during compilation and Testing I don't have to have  projectA only its interface. The question is where to place this interface (in repository) and how to get it in ProjectB

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whatever you decide to put your interface and asspciated data class (project A or project B svn or a new one), the first (and quite ovious) recomendation is that you put them together on its own library (DLL), without any dependency on other objects, so that becomes easy to share it across different projects.

To use it on a different project (do not matter if on another svn repository or not), you will have to give to that project physical access to this interface/data class. Being on its own dll and without the constraint of requiring other objects, it's a simple matter of add a reference of the library in the project.

With local copies of both projects, you don't need to copy the library itself into the other project.

In any case, you have to think well of your interface and data, so that you do not contantly make changes to them, in order to avoid having problems of compatibility between the projects. If you need to "add" something to the interface because of new features, create a new interface instead (and put it on other DLL). This way you will maintain compatibility with other projects that do not implement the new features.

If the data associated with the interface is so specific that any class implementing this interface will be used ONLY BY project A, so, the obvious place to put the DLL is into the project A. Usually this is the case when a software has the aability to use plugins. The interfaces are in a dll that can be "public" provided to plugin developers that do not have access to the main project itself. This is so simple as to make the DLL available to download. Beijng the SAME dll used on both main project and plugins, there will be no problems (than the reason to not change it).

But if your interface is more "generic" and is used to create something like a framework, where different projects (not related/not dependent) can use it alone, than, the suggestion to separete it in a third project (with its own svn) is more interesting. Using good polices regarding the development of this interface, will be less problematic to mantain the framework.

In the comments you said you can relate the "interface" to the project A, but if you can use it in project B without project A being involved, you can relate the interface to project B as well, and so, the option of moving the interface/associated data to a separetely project is preferable.

In any case, the underline implementation is irrelevant, as the main reason why we use interfaces in C# is exactly to be able to use an object in a "generic way" whithout (necessarily) having to care about how it is implemented.